# Limit bandwidth on a per-app basis on OS X?

Tags: osx, internet

I have an app that is rather particular about my bandwidth - namely wanting nearly all of it. This app runs quite well when I don't have anything else open, but it starts to lag and sound ugly when I open a Chrome window and start browsing around.

I believe that if I could limit Chrome's bandwidth, and the bandwidth of a few other apps, I could continue to browse without causing this problem app to lag and jitter.

I'd like:

- To be able to limit individual app's bandwidth usage, much like I can with [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) for the whole machine.
- Only have this setting affect the apps I set it on.
- I don't care if it has a GUI or not. I live in the terminal 40% of the day, so meh.

Is there an app that can do this? I have administrator privs on OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 6):

For a graphical interface, try [throttled](http://intrarts.com/throttled.html).

Considering you are savvy, you can could also get creative with builtin OS tools, as detailed below.

I say creative because, to the best of the knowledge, they don't let you throttle specific applications, but you can throttle ports and addresses.

## ipfw

Using `ipfw` to throttle inbound traffic from standard HTTP and HTTPS ports, like so, should throttle Chrome and other browsers:

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 100Kbytes/s 
sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 443
sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 80
```

Remove the rules with:

```
sudo ipfw delete 1
```

---

## pfctl

Note, however that `ipfw` has been deprecated. It still works, but I would really like to give you a comparable command/configuration for its successor `pf/pfctl`.

Unfortunately, `pf` is rather obtuse, and I am not certain the current Mac OS X 10.9.2 kernel is properly configured to fully utilize it, vis-a-vis the error:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

If you would like to geek out, and get to a non-deprecated solution, here is a five second primer.

BSD's `pf` (packet filter) is an analog to the Linux tool `tc` (traffic control), and they allow you to create different types of scheduled queues for network packets.

You may be able to use a **Priority Queue** to make your greedy application's traffic process first. Or, use a **Class Based Queue** to explicitly restrict the bandwidth as with `ipfw`.

http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/queueing.html#priq

---

## Other Suggestions

Similar questions asked on other stackexchange sites:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/bandwidth-shaper-or-bandwidth-controller-app-for-mac-os-x

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac/46378#46378